# How to format gridview content when doing binding?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, binding

I am currently doing the data binding:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Priority" SortExpression="priority">
    <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:Label Visible="true" runat="server" ID="priorityLabel" Text='<%# bind("numberTemplatePriority") %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

However, I would like to get this value first: <%# bind("numberTemplatePriority") %>, which will bring an integer, an according to that value, I want to show an equivalent string. For example: if it is number 4, I want to show "Very Important".

I wouldn't like to modify the sql query since it is used in other parts of the application.

The GridView datasource is a dataset and "numberTemplatePriority" is one of its columns.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

```
<asp:Label 
   Visible="true" 
   runat="server" 
   ID="priorityLabel" 
   Text='<%# Eval("numberTemplatePriority").ToString()=="1" ? "Very Important" : 
       Eval("numberTemplatePriority").ToString()=="2" ? "Something" : "Nothing" %>'
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use RowDataBound event of the gridview.Try this.

```
protected void gv_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        Label lbl = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("priorityLabel");

        int number = Convert.ToInt32(lbl.Text);

        if (number == 4)
        {
            lbl.Text = "Very Important";
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Give the following a try :

```
<%# (Eval("numberTemplatePriority") == "Very Important") ? Response.Write("Very Imprortant") : Response.Write("Not Important") %>
```

But I think you need to handle this kind of situations on the sql query. This kind of implementations are not so good idea. It will make it hard to maintain your application in a long term.